# Interface does not update in willTransition(to: , with: ) without DispatchQueue.main.async

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I am trying to handle a device rotation, and (during the rotation process)  make some "efforts" to scroll my collectionView to specified item .
So if I do it in DispatchQueue.main.async() everything updates.

```
 override func willTransition(to newCollection: UITraitCollection, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator)
{ 
    DispatchQueue.main.async {    
    let indexPath = IndexPath(item: self.pageControl.currentPage, section: 0)
    self.collectionView.scrollToItem(at: indexPath, at: .centeredHorizontally, animated: true)
  }
}
```

But I do it just in willTransition func without involving DispatchQueue.main.async() interface doest not updates, nothing happens.

```
 override func willTransition(to newCollection: UITraitCollection, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator)
{  
    let indexPath = IndexPath(item: self.pageControl.currentPage, section: 0)
    self.collectionView.scrollToItem(at: indexPath, at: .centeredHorizontally, animated: true)
}
```

Why? What it it's(DispatchQueue in the context of willTrasition func) charm?

Comment: All display updates are made on main thread. `DispatchQueue.main.async` tells iOS to execute it on main thread

Comment: @GIJOW you only need to explicitly dispatch UI related tasks to the main thread in case the function call happened on another thread (which shouldn't be the case here, but can't tell for sure without more context)

Comment: more context? there is noting special just collectionView with image in it when i rotate to landscape it turns out collectionViewCell is not laying in the center so it try put it in the center if do it without dispatch,queue.async nothing changes if i do it in dispatch.queue.async it work. it try to get it why?

Answer (score 1):

Try using the coordinator so you scroll the collection view as part of the rotation.

```
override func willTransition(to newCollection: UITraitCollection, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator)
{
    coordinator.animate(alongsideTransition: { (context) in
        let indexPath = IndexPath(item: self.pageControl.currentPage, section: 0)
        self.collectionView.scrollToItem(at: indexPath, at: .centeredHorizontally, animated: true)
    }, completion: nil)
}
```

The most likely reason your code fails when not using `DispatchQueue.main.async` is that you end up trying to scroll too soon and when you do use it, the scrolling is delayed long enough to be effective.